# PYSimpleGUI Table that shows formatted data

Tags: python, pysimplegui

Im trying to obtain with PYSimpleGUI table with formatted numbers (no decimals numbers). I take data from Dataframe and able to create table but without formatting.  If I try to format numbers on dataframe directly with `style.format` then during Table creation I recieve "Styler error". So I understand that I have first push DF into Table creation and then somehow format values. How to change format to `{:,.0f}` in table view. I looked for examples and cookbook but found no information about that.

```
import pysimplegui as sg
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[100.045, 212504.4588], [34658.13489, 445598.465498], [546589.466, 646549.4847], [71214.4986, 8498779.46598]], columns=["A", "B"])
layout = [[sg.Table(values=df,
                    display_row_numbers=True,
                    auto_size_columns=False,
                    num_rows=min(25, len(data)))]

window = sg.Window('Table', layout, grab_anywhere=False)
event, values = window.read()
window.close()
```

So far I receive table that looks like:

```
   A           B
0  100.045     212504.4588
1  34658.13489 445598.465498
....
```

I would like to achieve table that looks like:

```
   A         B
0     100    212,504
1  34,658    445,598
....
```

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful to have the full error if you could add it.

Comment: Sure, Alan i clicked Post the Question too fast and was editing to show sample DF in my question - hope it`s now better to understand my question.

Comment: the code above doesn't run. will try to help though, i have experience with both dataframes and pysimplgui

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the data to requested format by yourself.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

data = [
    [100.045, 212504.4588],
    [34658.13489, 445598.465498],
    [546589.466, 646549.4847],
    [71214.4986, 8498779.46598],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["A", "B"])
table_data    = list(map(lambda x:list(map(lambda d:f'{d:,.0f}', x)), df.values.tolist()))
table_headers = df.columns.values.tolist()

layout = [[sg.Table(table_data, headings=table_headers, display_row_numbers=True,
    auto_size_columns=False, num_rows=min(25, len(data)))]]

sg.Window('Table', layout, grab_anywhere=False).read(close=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Along with a few other fixes to your code, you need to use  the package `numpy` as well to change the `dtype` from float64 to int64 shown in the code below

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def df_gui():
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A", "B"],
                      data=np.array([[100.045, 212504.4588], [34658.13489, 445598.465498], [546589.466, 646549.4847],
                                     [71214.4986, 8498779.46598]]))
    df['A'] = df['A'].astype(np.int64)
    df['B'] = df['B'].astype((np.int64))
    values = df.values.tolist()
    headers = df.columns.values.tolist()


    layout = [[sg.Table(headings=headers, values=values, display_row_numbers=True, auto_size_columns=False, num_rows=min(25, len(values)))]]

    window = sg.Window('Table', layout, grab_anywhere=False)
    while True:
        event, value = window.read()

        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            break
    window.close()
df_gui()
```

TIP: run `event, values = window.read()` in a `while True:` loop. this will keep the window open, reading the event and values when ever something is clicked, until the x is pressed in the window which `breaks` the loop